# INHERITANCE (PYTHON) -not able acess 'name' in child class but able to access method and class attributes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

class Parent:
country="India"

```
def func1(self,name):
    self.name=name
    print("hey there")
    print(name)
```

class Child(Parent):
Company="BMW"

```
def func2(self):
    print("comp=",self.Company)
    print(self.name)  #not working
```

Obj=Parent()

Obj.func1("ram")

Obj2=Child()

Obj2.func2()

Comment: `Obj2` will only have a `name` attribute if you call the `func1` method on it since that method creates the attribute. Until that is done, `Obj2` has no `name` attribute

Comment: Also, there is no multiple inheritance in your code.

Comment: ah yaah thanks..it is a single inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Parent:
    country = "India"

    def func1(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("hey there")
        print(name)

class Child(Parent):
    Company="BMW"

    def func2(self):
        print("comp=",self.Company)
        print(Parent.name) # access the attribute of Parent class

Obj=Parent()

Obj.func1("ram")

Parent.name = "ram" # explicitly create an attribute for Parent class

Obj2=Child()

Obj2.func2()
```

If you want to access the "name" attribute of Parent class then create it explicitly outside the class definition. Then you can access the "name" attribute using Parent class.

Hope this helps. It is working in my machine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Obj` and `Obj2` are distinct instances of two distinct classes. By calling `Obj.func1("ram")` you set `name` in `Obj` and it will not have any effect to `Obj2`. These instances have both different type and ID:

```
>>> type(Obj)
<class '__main__.Parent'>
>>> type(Obj2)
<class '__main__.Child'>
>>> print(Obj)
<__main__.Parent object at 0x7f64f03023d0>
>>> print(Obj2)
<__main__.Child object at 0x7f64f03022b0>
```

If you want to set `Obj2.name`, you have to call `Obj2.func1("ram")` before `Obj2.func2()`:

```
>>> Obj2=Child()
>>> print(Obj2.name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'name'
>>> Obj2.func1("ram")
hey there
ram
>>> print(Obj2.name)
ram
```

Comment: oh thanks at first I thought the same but  since we are inheriting I thought it was possible to inherit these instances as well

Comment: Hi. You are inheriting methods of the parent class, not inner state of the instance created from parent class.